# Как сделать перетекание цвета в меню как на картинке?

Tags: html, css, menu

Не могу понять как сделать выделенный элемент с перетеканием цвета из красного в черный. Нужно ли использовать background-image или можно обойтись только css или вообще есть другой способ?

[image: Меню страницы]

Comment: это изображение , либо SVG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте лучше background-image (файл PNG с альфа-каналом). Сделать это на CSS можно, но на порядок сложнее и больше сложностей с кросс-браузерной совместимостью.

Также можно сделать через SVG, но этот способ схож с наложением изображения, только разница в том, что будет накладываться наполовину закрашенное изображение SVG.